# How can I create a Map with non-null values from a set of nullable items in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, functional-programming

In the Kotlin code, I want to add two fields to the map like this:

```
val myMap: Map<Type, List<Parameter>> = mapOf(
    Pair(Type.POST, request.postDetails.postParameters),//postDetails can be nullable
    Pair(Type.COMMENT, request.commentDetails.commentParameters)//commentDetails can be nullable
)
```

The above code is showing error at `postDetails.postParameters` and `commentDetails.commentParameters` because they can be nullable.

How can I create a `map` inplace like this instead of creating a variable and updating it where I want to keep the pair only in the case the value is not `null`?

Comment: Try changing `List<Parameter>` to `List<Parameter>?`.

Comment: But I don't want null values to be in the map

Comment: Do you mean that if `request.postDetails.postParameters` is `null`, the map shouldn't have the `Type.POST` key in it?

Comment: yes, it shouldn't have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just write my own factory methods for it, and call these methods instead.

```
fun <K, V> mapOfNullableValues(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V?>): Map<K, V> =
    pairs.mapNotNull { (k, v) ->
        if (v != null) k to v else null
    }.toMap()

fun <K, V> mutableMapOfNullableValues(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V?>): MutableMap<K, V> =
    pairs.mapNotNull { (k, v) ->
        if (v != null) k to v else null
    }.toMap(mutableMapOf())
```

By writing your own factory methods, you get to work with an array of `Pair`s, which is way easier than modifying the use site in place.

Note that compared to the built in builders, these methods create an extra list.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found out without adding a lot of extra code would be to add code to add `emptyList` in the case it is `null` and remove them later.

Something like this:

```
val myMap: Map<Type, List<Parameter>> = mapOf(
    Pair(Type.POST, request.postDetails?.postParameters ?: listOf()),
    Pair(Type.COMMENT, request.commentDetails?.commentParameters ?: listOf())//commentDetails can be nullable
).filter{ it.value.isNotEmpty() }
```